# Different ways i could append my JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a array of in the following format.

```
timeSeries = [{ key: 'Time Series Data',
                values: [ { 'label': '01/01', 'value': 20 } ] }];
```

now i have typescript object that has properties which i need to map to the label value and value value.

```
export interface Plot {
  dateLabel: string;
  x: number;
}
```

my plotArray is as follows

```
plotArray =   [ { 'label': '01/03', 'value': 30 }, { 'label': '01/04', 'value': 40 }];
```

What are the different ways i could append my plotArray to values in the timeSeries in javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that in many different ways such as:

1. Using concat

   `timeSeries.values = timeSeries.values.concat(plotArray);`
2. Using [lodash's](https://lodash.com/) concat function

   `timeSeries.values = _.concat(timeSeries.values, plotArray);`
3. Using ES6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

   `timeSeries.values = [...timeSeries.values, ...plotArray];`

   or

   `timeSeries.values.push(...plotArray);`
4. Lastly you can iterate through the plotArray and push it one by one.

   `plotArray.forEach(function(plot) { 
      timeSeries.values.push(plot)
    });`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ES6(or newer), you could use the spread operator([Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)):

```
timeSeries.values.push(...plotArray)
```